# HTML / CSS: Hide Text and Show Border

Tags: html, css, border

How can I show only the border of a div, but not the text using CSS?

Comment: Are you able to wrap the contents of the div in another element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not well supported by IE, but you could use:

```
#mydiv { color:rgba(0,0,0,0); border:1px solid #000 }
```

This makes the text color fully transparent, but leaves the border visible.

Comment: `color: transparent` is also an option, and I think it's better supported by Internet Explorer too.

Answer (score 4):

A simple cross-browser solution is the Phark "text indent" method. It's usually used for image replacement.

```
div.example {
   border: 2px solid red;
   /* Hide text inside "off left" */
   text-indent: -10000px;
   /* Make sure to set a width and height */
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Pros:

- Doesn't need any extra elements
- Works in screen-readers

Cons:

- Doesn't work in IE5

Answer (score 2):

You can make the text the same color as the div's background.  Or nest the text inside another div.